# Need regex which accept only 4 alpha numeric words and accept period, hyphen and underscore in between

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to write a regex to accept only 4 words and in between the words accept special characters like period(.), hyphen(-) and underscore(*). Also if I use hyphen (-) or underscore (*) between the words then it is going to be considered as one word. For ex:
a_b.c.d.e --> Here the word length is 4 as a_b is considered as 1 word.
a.b-c.d.e --> Still it is 4 words as b-c should be considered as 1 word.

The special characters can't be the same immediately before the next word (means no duplicate spl chars immd).

Also I want this regex to accept only lowercase alphabets and numbers. The accepted pattern examples are as below.

**Valid cases**

1. a.b.c.d
2. a-b.c.d.e
3. a_b.c.d.e
4. a.b-c.d.e
5. a.b_c.d.e

**Invalid cases**

1. a..b.c.d.e
2. a--b.c.d.e
   3.a__b.c.d.e
3. a_b.c.d
4. a-b.c.d

I tried the below regex and it works upto some extent.

```
^[a-z0-9]+(?:[._-][a-z0-9]+)*$
```

The above one is failing in scenarios like

- if I provide more than 4 words.

Comment: How is this regex trying to limit the result to exactly 4 words?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow! You seem to be under the impression that StackOverflow is a site where you post a problem and get some code in return. This is in fact not the case. Your question will most likely be closed or even deleted shortly. To prevent this from happening in the future, please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [take a look at the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help). In particular, [make yourself famlilar as to what is regarded as on-topic around here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: `The special characters can't be the same immediately before the next word (means no duplicate spl chars immd)` Can you clarify this

Comment: @ScottHunter: I tried doing that limit and it didn't work. So checking if there is a repeat to check to accept only 4 words.

Comment: @anubhava: What is meant is it can't accept a..b or a--b or a__D.

Comment: Just a shot in the dark `^(?!.*[._-]{2})[a-z0-9][a-z0-9._-]*([._-])[a-z0-9][a-z0-9._-]*(?:\1[a-z0-9._=]*[a-z0-9]){2}$` https://regex101.com/r/gLCHBu/1

Comment: So `a.b-c.d.e` has 4 words or 5?

Comment: @anubhava: It is 4 as - and _ delimiter considering as 1 word. Like a_b is one word. where as a.b is considered as 2 words.

Comment: @Thefourthbird: Thanks for the reply. Let me test it and will let you know if it is working.

Comment: @NarendraKumar, try [this](https://regex101.com/r/NXXX7C/2): 
`(?<=\s)(([a-z]+((((?<spc>\-|\_)(?!\k<spc>))*[a-z]+)*)?)+\.?){4}(?=\s)`
if it works for you, it will be easy to reverse explain :)

Comment: @Thefourthbird: it is failing with the 4th word check.

Comment: @NarendraKumar My suggestion would be to update the question with a very clear description of what you want to match and what you consider a word.

Comment: @Thefourthbird: Updated the question with more information explaining considerations for one words vs multiple.

Comment: Observations: (a) If it is valid to use a hyphen as a word _separator_, but it is also valid to use a hyphen (or underscore...) _within_ a word, then how can you tell if any given hyphen (or underscore...) is being used as a separator or not? (b) Assuming point (a) can be addressed, at some point you may end up with a regex which may be unacceptably difficult to understand, and equally difficult to maintain. Do you really _need_ a pure regex solution here? Or do you just _want_ one?

Comment: @NarendraKumar: Will `^[\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+){3}$` work for you?